# Is there a way to find all View.GONE elements on a page?

Tags: java, android, view

I have an android application where I'm hiding and showing different custom items on the page. Is there a way to loop through all the items on the page that are set to view.gone or am I going to have to do an if for each ID?

Thanks a lot

Comment: for page you mean layout?

Comment: Sorry yeah, they're hidden in code, but it's the layout I mean yeah

Comment: You can do a traversal of the entire UI tree (like HierarchyViewer), but this is too slow to be practical. You're better off going through a list of known ID's and even better off if you've cached the lookups somewhere, such as in instance fields of a custom view or in a View Holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find hidden views, you can do something like:

```
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

    int childViews = parentLayout.getChildCount();
    List<View> hiddenViews = new ArrayList<View>();

    for (int i = 0; i < childViews; i++) {
        View v = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            hiddenViews.add(v);
        }
    }
```

In this example, the `List<View> hiddenViews` will contain all views with visibility of `View.GONE`.

Answer (score 1):

While you are setting their visibility to `GONE`, at same time add them to a predifined `arraylist`, that way you'll always have a record of views which are not visible.

```
In OnCreate:
hiddenViews = new ArrayList<View>();
```

While setting their visibility:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
hiddenViews.add(view);
```

Now, you can access `hiddenViews` arrayList at any point within `activity`.